# Seeing exception information in AppCode

Tags: crash-reports, appcode

I've been testing AppCode and I can't seem to find any information as to WHY an app is crashing.

I've added an exception breakpoint and I can see the line of code causing the crash but no info on why.

In Xcode the exception reason is printed into the console but in AppCode I just get "Exception = Exception Breakpoint".

Can someone point me in the direction of getting useful information out of the crash.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

AppCode, Choses Run, View Break points settings, Click on "Log message to console" by default it is off.

Command liners use, shift-fn-command-f8

[image: AppCode Run, View Breakpoint or shift-fn-command-f8]

Comment: This still doesn't do anything other than logging "Breakpoint reached: when any is thrown". In Xcode I get ... `logoView is not a key in the views dictionary. 
V:|-36-[logoView(43)]-36-[emailTextField(44)]-[passwordTextField(44)]-20-[signInButton(44)]`

Comment: They instruments, look for zombies.

Answer (score 1):

AppCode also prints the exception in the console, providing that you launch the app in debug mode (as, actually, the debugger does it).

Comment: Yes, but that only happens **after** the exception breakpoint is hit